# How do you use memcached (not memcache) with PHP

Tags: php

On the first page, I have this

```
// start memcached
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
$key = 'test_' . $ID_ref;
$test_data = array(....);
$m->set($key, $test_data);
// end memcached
```

OK, so far. On the next page,

```
// start memcached
$m->connect('localhost', 11211);
var_dump($m->get($key));
// end memcached
```

The errors are:

1. Undefined variable: m and
2. Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on a non-object

Where did I go wrong.

Comment: U forgot to degine memcached object in next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on next page aswell:

```
$m = new Memcached();

$m->connect('memcache_host', 11211);
```

PHP manual will help your for furthur instructions read this

```
http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.connect.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now. I get this error: "Call to undefined method Memcached::connect()"

Comment: Ahan great now chose the best answer and mark as accepted this will help for others my friend

Comment: Ahan means another new error ohh . My answer is related to yur question now foe this error chk memcached class and check is there connect function available or not undefine means function not exist @bryan

Comment: phpinfo shows that memcached is installed by webhost. It seems that memcached does not support connect() "http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php". What should I use instead?